# How can I change php.ini settings so I can alter the maximum data being sent through a file transfer?

Tags: php

I have created a form with a file upload script, but when i run it, my browser tells me that the maximum upload limit has been exceeded. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By file transfer hope you meant file upload.

There are two values to be set to change the file transfer size `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your php.ini. Please see the code below

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

You can set any number you want as required. 20M means 20 MB.

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.